# Remove ion-radio from ion-select - Ionic v4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I would like to remove ion-radio which are generated when i call ion-select (with a popover interface)

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Popover</ion-label>
    <ion-select interface="popover" placeholder="Select One">
      <ion-select-option value="brown">Brown</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="blonde">Blonde</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="black">Black</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="red">Red</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

the code above generates ion-radio elements in the shadow DOM.

I tried to select them (trying a display: none, or modifying a property with css4 (--border-width for example)).

I also tried the interfaceOptions method [interfaceOptions]="{cssClass:'custom-popover'}", without success.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Can you try with mode="ios".

```
<ion-select placeholder="Select One" mode="ios">
  <ion-select-option value="f">Female</ion-select-option>
  <ion-select-option value="m">Male</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: did you tried with
.alert-radio-icon{
    display:none !important;
}

write this code in style.css file instead of writing it in component.scss file

Comment: does not work too. i think i should create my own popover via PopoverController

Comment: where did you added your styles.

Comment: as you told me. In the global file styles.scss

Comment: are you able see this code in browser while inspecting that element.

Comment: finally i re created a popoverController to work around the problem

Answer (score 2):

If anyone comes looking for an answer, simple solution:

1. add the attribute [interfaceOptions]="customOptions" to the ion-select tag
2. in the component.ts file add a property (before constructor)
   customOptions = { mode: 'ios' };